# Contact/Subscription Form not sending all selected/entered information over to Email

Tags: php, html, radio-button

Searched around and could not find/figure out how to fix my problem.

Created a form that, when email is entered and radio button is selected, an email will be sent to me with that information. However, the email address is coming over, but the radio button selection is not. I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="subscriber_info">
    <div class="subscriber_header">
        Subscribe to Scarlet & Maize
    </div>
    <div class="subscriber_image">
        <img src="NEW LOGO-150.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="subscriber_content">
        Receive fresh content for your favorite team straight to your inbox!<br /><br />

        Select your Team(s):<br />
        <div class="selection">
            <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Michigan Wolverines" checked="checked" /> Michigan Wolverines<br />
            <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Ohio State Buckeyes" /> Ohio State Buckeyes<br />
            <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Both" /> Both
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subscriber_contact">

    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </form>  

</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "__________@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */


$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$likeit    = check_input($_POST['likeit']);


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
$website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "You have a new subscriber:

E-mail: $email
Favorite Team?: $likeit



End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
<?php echo $myError; ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this `$likeit = $_POST['likeit']`

Since I can't find where you're defining $likeit

Comment: even when I added that it still would not work. i have edited the code to reflect the addition.